# (Short proof verification) Problem related to distance to a set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, compactness

I have this previous result:

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space and $K\subset E$ a compact subset. Then, for all $x\in E$ there is a $k_x \in K$ such that $d(x, K)=d(x, k_x)$, where $d(x, K)=\inf\{d(x, k):k\in K\}$

The problem is to show that in case $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual distance, the previous statement holds for $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (a closed not empty subset) instead of a compact one.

My proof is as follows:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Take $c_0 \in C$. Now set $r=d(x, c_0)$, and consider $W=C \cap \bar{B}(x, r)$ (that is the closed ball of center $x$ and radius $r$).  Because $W$ is the intersection of two closed sets, it is closed. It is also bounded, because it is contained in a ball. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ a closed and bounded subset is compact, so apply the previous result to get $k_x \in W$ such that $d(x, k_x)=d(x, W)$. To see that $d(x, k_x)=d(x, C)$ we consider the definition of distance from a point to a set and the following inequalities: $d(x, k_x) \leq d(x, c_0)=r \leq d(x, k) \ \forall k \in C\backslash W$, so $d(x, k_x)=d(x, C)$

As requested in the comments, I edit the last sentence:
As $d(x, k_x)=\inf \{d(x, w) : w \in W\}$, and $c_0 \in W$, $d(x,k_x) \leq d(x, c_0)=r$. However, $d(x, c)>r \ \forall c \in C$ such that $c\notin W$, so $d(x, k_x)=d(x, C)$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything made sense to me until the last sentence, when I became unsure what was happening. Why do you consider $C\setminus W$? What is $K$ now?

Comment: Good question +1